# Taylor's Theorem for 2D function

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I am doing a numerical analysis course and we are looking at numerical methods for solving initial value problems.

For example: methods such as $y_{n+1} = y_n+\frac{h}{2}(f(t_n,y_n) + f(t_{n+1}, y_{n+1}))$

In the book I am using, they say that we should expand $y'(t_{n-1})$ using Taylor's Theorem as follows: note that $y'(t) = f(t,y(t))$

$y'(t_{n-1}) = y'(t_n) -hy''(t_n)$

Answer (score 1):

They are expanding $y'$ about $t_{n}$:
$$y'(t_{n-1}) = y'(t_{n}) + (t_{n-1}-t_{n})y''(t_n) + \frac{1}{2}(t_{n-1}-t_n)^2y'''(t_n) + \ldots$$
presumably $t_n-t_{n-1}$ is the time step $h$, and for $h$ sufficiently small the higher-order terms can be neglected.